# Set parent of model during creation

Tags: python, django

**Background info:**

I just started using web frameworks a couple of weeks ago, and I figured that I should try RoR first. When I ran into some deadends with RoR, I thought I'd try out a few others, which directed me towards Django. I've been an avid Ruby and Python user for a couple of years, and this site has helped me out of numerous problems. I'm trying to set up a product database for an inventory room, using a Product model and a Location model. The inventory room consists of isles of racks, which hold shelves, which hold boxes. Using this, I've put together a makeshift coordinate system using the isle, rack (called segment), shelf, and box. For example, a location of "G1C4" would be on isle G, rack 1, shelf C, and box 4. In RoR, I was able to create a Product object using the location name, product name, quantity, and MPN (manufacturer part number). When the Product was created, the Product would be added to the corresponding Location using Regex.

**Problem:**

**EDIT:**

How could the model's methods be overloaded to auto-populate the location field with a matching Location before the Product is saved?

**Current Code:**

Product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    mpn = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

Location model:

```
class Location(models.Model):

    isle = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    segment = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    shelf = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    box = models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

RoR equivalent:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :location, inverse_of: :products, foreign_key: "location_id"

before_validation do
    create_parent()
end

def create_parent()
    attrs = new_loc() # method that used Regex to find the coordinates

    Location.where(location_name: self.location_name).first_or_initialize do |loc|
        loc.isle_id = attrs['isle']
        loc.segment_id = attrs['segment']
        loc.shelf_id = attrs['shelf']
        loc.box_id = attrs['box']
        loc.item_list = []
        loc.save!
    end

    loc = Location.where(location_name: self.location_name).take!
    loc.item_list << self.mpn
    loc.save!

    self.location_id = loc.id

end
```

**EDIT:**
I was reviewing my post, and I realized that the title wasn't quite related to the question.

Comment: before expanding my answer, I would like to point that with this model structure, even if you have multiple products (setting a quantity > 1), you would end up having all of them in the same location, because the FK is on the Product model, is this what you want? I also assume that location_name would hold something like "G1C4" on product creation, is this correct?

Comment: Both of those assumptions are indeed correct. I'm attempting to create a one to many relationship (or in django's terms, many to one) with many Products in each Location. As with your second assumption, yes, location_name would hold something of that matter, and that is what will be used to assign the Product to the appropriate Location.

Comment: I've expanded the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is really simple, you just create a location

```
l = Location(...)
l.save()
```

and a product, with that location

```
p = Product(location=l, ...)
p.save()
```

or

```
p = Product(...)
p.location = l
p.save()
```

**EDIT:**

assuming that product.location would hold something like "G1C4" upon creation (so for example you create your product with something like `p = Product(location_name="G1C4", product_name="cisco 123", quantity=3, mpn="something")` ) you could override the save method of `Product` to automatically create or set a corresponding location for that product

```
class Product(models.Model):

    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    mpn = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        isle = self.location_name[0]
        segment = self.location_name[1]
        shelf = self.location_name[2]
        box = self.location_name[3]
        self.location = Location.objects.get_or_create(
                            isle=isle,
                            segment=segment,
                            shelf=shelf,
                            box=box)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

so when you call `p.save()` a matching location is set for the location attribute, if that location doesn't exists yet it is created automatically.

Comment: Where would this go? A view?

Comment: @RussellHueske wherever you create those objects

Comment: Could a create method be used to do this every time a Product object is created?

Comment: @RussellHueske could you please reformulate the last question? Maybe if you have a specific use case modify the question with that (also in pseudocode if you have the idea but trying to find how an implementation would look like), but anyway there is plenty of documentation that deals with how to create Model objects, starting with a ModelForm or similar.